# Parse/Render .ajax response html in contenteditable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Hi Guys I want a straight forward approach to making my HTML ajax retrieved response to be displayed rendered in the contenteditable#div.
My HTML:

```
<div class="editable form-control msg" data-type="text" data-placeholder="Your Message here" id="msg"  data-name="msg" contenteditable="true"></div>

<select id="Response" onChange="addSignature(\'Response\')" name="Response"><!-- -->
    <option selected="selected" value="default"> ---Select a Signature to add ---</option>
                <option value="TY">Thank You</option>
                <option value="SUS">See You Soon</option>
                <option value="BR">Best Regards</option>
```

There is my JQuery that retrieves the appropriate response

```
//Add Response function
function addResponse(obj)
{
    var Response = $k('#'+obj).val();
    var theResponse = {'response':Response }
    $k.ajax({
        url: 'inc/runUtilities.php',
        data: theResponse,
        type: 'POST',
    beforeSend: function(url,data) 
    {
        $k('#msg').html('<img src="images/page-loader.gif" height="80px" width="80px" />').fadeIn('slow');
    },
        success: function(data)
        {
                $k('#msg').html(data).fadeIn('slow');
        }
    });

}
```

Again, what i want to do is get the appropriate response on selection change and display a HTML render - but i keep getting the coding. Any advise guys, and i have checked a number of questions here on stackoverflow already.

Comment: The function is called addResponse but your HTML contains onChange="addSignature(\'Response\')".  Other than that I don't see anything wrong.  What is the output you are currently getting?

Comment: Hi Phari, addResponse/addSignature still get the ajax-response in tags and not renders.

Comment: Log the ajax response to the console to see whether it is HTML-encoded.  It is if the angle brackets have been replaced with &lt; and &gt;  If so, the issue is on the server side.